# Breadth First Search Java shortest distance

Tags: java

I have written a bfs algorithm but know I have to find out the shortest distance between two points. Can I somehow implement it within my code?

```
public static void bfsearch(Graph<Vertex, Edge<Vertex>> G, Vertex S){

        State[] color = new State [G.getNumberVertices()];
        int[] dist = new int [G.getNumberVertices()];
        Vertex[] pred = new Vertex [G.getNumberVertices()];
        Vertex temp;

        for(int i=0; i<color.length; i++){
            color[i] = State.WHITE;
            dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            pred[i] = null;
        }
        color[S.getId()] = State.GREY; dist[S.getId()] = 0; pred[S.getId()] = null;     
        Queue<Vertex> Q = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        Q.add(S);
        while(!Q.isEmpty()){
            temp = Q.remove();
            for(Vertex x:G.getNeighbours(temp)){
                if(color[x.getId()] == State.WHITE ){
                    color[x.getId()] = State.GREY;
                    dist[x.getId()] = dist[temp.getId()] + 1;
                    pred[x.getId()] = temp;
                    Q.add(x);
                }
            }
            color[temp.getId()] = State.BLACK;
            System.out.println("(Node "+temp+", "+"Pred="+pred[temp.getId()]+" Distance="+dist[temp.getId()]+")");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the edges have different weight? Or the distance between points is same?

Comment: It is the same. In this case always 1.

Comment: Then, yes, use one point as origin, the shortest distance between these two points is the distance value when the sink point is found first time(when its color is set GREY).